# What is the best way to save current language(UICulture) in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I want to set language based on requested url. I am doing this with Session for now. But I can't access Session in **Route Constraints**. The problem occurs here: returns error because '*HttpContext.Current.Session*' is null in RouteConstraint.

```
public class ngnRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
       ...
       Tools.GetCurrentLang();// trying to get language
       ...
    }
}
```

***In Tools:***

```
public static string GetCurrentLang()
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Lang"] != null)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Session["Lang"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLang"];
    }
}
```

> Also I tried to add: **runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"** and romove and add **Seesion** module but I got same error.
>
> ```
> <system.webServer>
>   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
>     <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
>   </modules>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

**QUESTION:**
What could I do? Can I handle this problem with session or cookie? What do you suggest? Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing along the HttpContextBase parameter to your GetCurrentLang() method?

```
public static string GetCurrentLang(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext.Session["Lang"] != null)
    {
        return httpContext.Session["Lang"].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultLang"];
    }
}
```

Comment: No, but `HttpContextBase httpContext`'s **httpContext.Session** is null in Match function. The problem is: Session is not initialized yet, i think.